# RPM + cant find rpm after rpm install

Tags: linux, rpm

please advice why I cant find the rpm that I installed.
I am try to check by rpm -qa | grep test ( see the example in install the rpm: )
but seems that rpm isnt installed why?

build the RPM:

```
 [root@linux /usr/src/redhat/SOURCES]#  rpm -ba   /usr/src/redhat/SPECS/my_spec.spec
 Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /var/tmp/test.sh
 Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/SRPMS/test.sh-6.2-2.src.rpm
```

install the rpm:

```
   [root@linux /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/i386]# rpm -Uvh  /root/rpmbuild/SRPMS/test.sh-6.2-2.src.rpm 
   1:test.sh                ########################################### [100%]

   [root@linux /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/i386]# rpm -qa | grep test

   no results ?
```

the spec file:

```
  Summary: An example tool. To show a simple rpm build of the tool.
  Name: test.sh
  Version: 6.2
  Release: 2
  Source:/root/test.sh
  Group: Development/Debuggers
  BuildRoot:/var/tmp/test.sh
  License: OtherLicense
  %description
```

Comment: I try  rpm -Uvh  /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/test.sh-6.2-2.src.rpm
   1:test.sh                ########################################### [100%] but the same problem

Answer (score 4):

You installed the source rpm instead of the actual rpm:

```
rpm -Uvh /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/test.sh-6.2-2.rpm
```

Comment: I try it but the same problem -:(

Comment: @Jon even after you installed the file above?  It looks like from another comment you tried installing `.src.rpm` again and not just the `.rpm` file.

Comment: @Wes but I not have test.sh-6.2-2.rpm
I have only the test.sh-6.2-2.src.rpm ?

Comment: @Wes even if I rename the file and perfrom the rpm -Uvh /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/test.shet -6.2-2.rpm 1:test.sh ########################################### [100%] then I not get the test.sh from rpm -qa|grep test

Comment: you can't rename a source file.  When you build the rpm it produces what is called a source rpm in `/root/rpmbuild/SRPMS/test.sh-6.2-2.src.rpm` and the actual rpm you want to install in `/root/rpmbuild/RPMS/test.sh-6.2-2.rpm`.  Notice the difference in the directories and the file names.  It is very important.  Please make sure you have the actual rpm in the RPMS directory and install that file.

Answer (score 2):

rpmbuild outputs two files:

1. A source RPM (SRPM), located in SRPMS/
2. A binary RPM, located in RPMS//

As Wes noted, you've installed the SRPM. You need to install the RPM, which is located in your RPMS/i386/ subdir. Don't rename the SRPM, you need to look for the file located in the RPM folder and install it:

```
rpm -Uvh RPMS/i386s/test.sh-6.2-2.i386.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

When you install src.rpm it ends up in

```
  ~/rpmbuild/SPEC
  ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES
```

If you want to rebuild and get binary rpm you should:

```
  rpmbuild -ba test.sh-6.2-2.src.rpm
```

or even better

```
  mock test.sh-6.2-2.src.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
rpm -q test.sh-6.2-2
```

or

```
rpm -q test.sh-6.2-2.src
```